# AngularJS $http date header

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to retrieve the $http date header from an AngularJS $http.get request so I can get the server time.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($http,$scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://graph.facebook.com/facebook'}).then(function(response){
    console.log(response);
  })
});
```

I can't seem to retrieve the Date header although when I inspected on chrome tools the date header was there.

Answer (score 6):

try this:

```
   $http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://graph.facebook.com/facebook'}).then(function(response){
         var data = response.data,
            status = response.status,
            headers = response.headers(),
            config = response.config;
      })
```

`headers` will contain:

```
headers: {
  "date": "Mon, 02 Mar 2015 23:02:51 GMT",
  "content-encoding": "gzip",
  "server": "Apache",
  "vary": "Accept-Encoding",
  "content-type": "text/html",
  "connection": "Keep-Alive",
  "keep-alive": "timeout=10, max=500",
  "content-length": "39"
}
```

to access date:

```
headers.date
```

Since it's a CORS request to facebook api: The response header will contain only

```
Content-Type
Last-modified
Content-Language
Cache-Control
Expires
Pragma
```

The issue is because of missing `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` from request Header. To fix this we need to add `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *` to request header in your run method

Comment: How come it doesnt work for me? http://plnkr.co/edit/SvPECqJi1npYRqDcyBqF?p=preview

Comment: small change: it should be response.headers()

Comment: In your response there is no date field, When i tried to print the headers. I got: cache-control: "private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"content-type: "application/json; charset=UTF-8"expires: "Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"pragma: "no-cache" only

Comment: Yeah thats what I'm asking... because the header does come with the response but theres no way to retrieve it?

Comment: include Access-Control-Allow-Headers: * to your request header

Comment: I have the same issue. The Date header is in the response, I can see it with the browser debugger, but i can't get it via response.headers(). What does it has to do with CORS?.

Comment: @YangLi Why did you marked this answer as correct if you said "It has nothing to do with CORS?.

Comment: @jgomo3 Sorry, I can't remember why.  I'm assuming that adding Access-Control-Allow-Headers: * solved my issue

Comment: @YangLi, Hope we fixed it on that day by adding the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *` to the header. And then you accepted the answer. May I know why it's removed now from accepted answer? If you tried some other method to make it work, do share it so that we can be aware of it.

Comment: @mohamedrias, in hindsight, I dont think this issue was solved. I left it to do other stuff and just accepted the answer inadvertently. Someone else now has the same issue and this did not help them, I removed the accepted answer so someone might come and try to help them.

Comment: @YangLi oh I was not aware of it.. Will check and update the answer then.. Thanks for letting me know that the issue is open still =)